# Blazor - Connection closed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I keep getting the error message "Cannot send data if the connectionis not in the 'Connected' State" in my Blazor server app. The problem occurs irregularly and only on the server (Windows 2016), not in my local development environment (Win 10 - VS 2019).

Attached is a screenshot of the console.

Any idea why the connection keeps closing?

With many thanks in advance
Peter Breuer
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why the connection keeps closing?

Yes, it's very clearly stated that there was an unhandled exception on the current circuit. Circuit objects are very sensitive and their misuse may lead to security issues and most importantly to a chaotic state in your application. Therefore, if an exception is thrown and not handled properly, Blazor immediately closes the connection. That's the best way to prevent serious issues. Now, when the connection is closed, your application is actually dead. Consequently, many other exceptions are thrown.

But the issue is not with your connection. A closed connection is only the symptom; you need, however, look for the underlying issues from which your application suffers. Handling exception not only will prevent the closing of the connection, but can also point you out in direction of the issues.

Note: Is your Web Api is running ? Start first with ascertaining this. Check your app settings configurations, etc. Do you use HttpContext in your application ? HttpContext is not available in Server Blazor App as Blazor employs SignalR, not HTTP as a means of transportations, but developers on local development devises think that using HttpContext is fine, but after deploying their app to a server they start to understand the warning they refused to heed. I can go on like this...there are many roads to a place...

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I was on vacation and am only now back online :-)
I use IHttpContextAccessor (injected by services.AddHttpContextAccessor();) - can this already cause the problems?